Asimptotic contur integral from q-pochhummer symbol power -0,5 multiplied with exponent
I tried to get asimptotical behaivior of the function $f(z)$ when complex $ z \to \infty $ of the following expression:
$$ f(z) = (z; q)_{\infty}^{-1/2}, 0<q<1 $$
I would be very grateful for any help.
Actually I need to calculate circular integral down semicircle on complex plane:
$$g(x) = \int \exp(-izx) f(z) \ dz, z = R \exp(i \phi), 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi , R \to \infty$$
